# Vue 3 - mounted() not getting called on component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a dead simple Vue 3 component which looks identical to some of the examples in the docs. The code is below:

```
// Typewriter.vue

<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <p>{{ text }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "typewriter",
  props: {
    phrase: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      text: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

I then render this in another component via:

```
<template>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <typewriter phrase="some text" />
</template>

<script>
import Typewriter from "@/components/Typewriter.vue";

export default {
  name: "bio",
  components: {
    Typewriter
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

However, `mounted()` does not seem to get called? If I change it to `setup()` then anything inside the method does get called, but of course this doesn't work for my case because I need access to `this` on the component.

Am I missing something obvious? Apologies, new to Vue and learning.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, I'm seeing the console.log.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out the problem was a tutorial I followed, explicitly in the Webpack build (I'm using a Rails app with webpacker), set the following:

```js
...
environment.plugins.prepend(
  "Define",
  new DefinePlugin({
    __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false, // This is the problem
    __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
  })
);

...
```

Which of course turns off the options API and forces you to use the composition API (which I am not).

Comment: You are my hero today =D 
I spend too much time wondering why my Vue components were not working

Answer (score -1):

Your code works. [Check this out](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Your problem is elsewhere.

If you want to show the phrase, change `text` to `phrase` in `Typewriter.vue`

```
<p>{{ phrase }}</p>
```

Your code uses the local variable `text` which is just an empty string.